# Android Application opens again after finishing

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

In my main menu, I try to finish the app using the back button on the phone and an `AlertDialog`.

Here is my code:

```
    Button zumspiel;
    Button lineup;
    Button social;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);


        lineup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLineup);
        lineup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent lineup = new Intent(MainMenu.this, LineUp_Auswahl.class);
                startActivity(lineup);


            }
        });

        zumspiel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btZumSpiel);
        zumspiel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent spiel = new Intent(MainMenu.this, VormSpiel.class);
                startActivity(spiel);

            }
        });




        social = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSocial);
        social.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent high = new Intent(MainMenu.this, SozialeMedien.class);
                startActivity(high);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Wüstenfest App schließen")
            .setMessage("Bist du sicher dass du die App beenden möchtest?")
            .setPositiveButton("Ja!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("Nein, natürlich nicht!", null)
        .show();
    }
```

Now my problem is, that when I press `Ja` on the `AlertDialog`, the current `MainMenu` Activity is closing but a new one opens. When I try to exit here again, it works. What is wrong with my way?

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO THIS

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

When your process abruptly dies, Android tries to recreate it. If you just want the Activity to close, call `finish()` or `super.onBackPressed()`.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to show an exit dialog anyway. Users already have expectations about what BACK should do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried the killProcess because finish() causes the same issue I wrote above.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the entire `onBackPressed()` method and just press back? Does your Activity come back? I want to see if your dialog code has any effect on the behavior, since the usual behavior of BACK is to finish the Activity.

Comment: When I comment it out, it is the same issue. I realized that this just happens when I come from a different acitivity, when I start and close the application does not open again..

Comment: Perhaps there is something that causes another instance of `MainMenu` activity to be in the history stack. Try reading through this and see if anything might help: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html